# How to set :having parameter equal to value in select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method that uses the :having parameter to make an active record query. I'd like to set the parameter equal to whatever a user selects from a select box.

For example, if the user selects the value "Happy" from the select box, I'd like the active record query to filter down to records in the column "Mood" that match "Happy". Currently I can manually set the parameter to a specific value, but I'd like it to be variable.

How do I go about linking the :having parameter to the value from a select box? Thanks!

Edit with code:

Select Box:

```
<%= options_for_select([[''],['Happy'],['Sad'], :selected => :mood) %>
```

Method Snippet:

```
group("gender","mood").having("gender=?","male").having("mood=?", :mood)
```

I know that this is not correct, I've been playing with the code and this is what I currently have - not necessarily what I should have.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please add that to your question.

Comment: `@group=User.where(:gender=>'male', :mood=>'happy')`? If gender and mood is columns of user record

Comment: The problem is, that would hard code mood as Happy. I want a user to be able to select Happy or Sad from a drop-down select box and be able to filter the data in different ways accordingly.